# Why is my Remix app rendering twice without any outlets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

My Remix app seems to be rendered twice, even when removing all routes and components.  I'm a little unsure as to why.

If I comment everything out, and leave myself with just `/app/root.tsx` as per below, I can still see the browser log out "app render" twice.  If I remove the Outlet from the App component below, it is still logged twice.

```js
export default function App() {
  console.log("app render");
  return (
    <html lang="en" className="h-full bg-gray-100">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body className="h-full">
        <Outlet />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I'm not sure if this is normal behaviour or not?  It doesn't seem like it's right, and it's causing me a few state issues in my components, so would like to address the root cause if possible.

Comment: Is your `<App />` component rendered in `React.StrictMode`?

Comment: Not something I've done, the App component is loaded in by Remix in the `entry.client.tsx` file

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with how remix works, but I'm guessing that it wraps your `<App />` component in strict-mode (I couldn't find anything in the docs that confirm this though). You usually see this double-invoking type of behaviour when your component is in strict-mode, as its purpose is to help catch side-effects. It could be worth pointing out the state issues you're having as it might be suggesting that you're doing something side-effect related in one of your components

Comment: @NickParsons thanks! Could you explain why this is causing a double render?

Comment: @KevinVugts React double invokes certain functions (such as the function component itself, the useEffect callback, etc.) to help you as a developer catch side effects within your code. You can read [this part](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) of the docs on more details about how this can help catch "side effects". React's new beta docs covers this well also [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development)